# How to Parse the xml file using pyspark and convert it to a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have tried using the pyspark read .But this is not working since this is not able to fetch the root tag details.Results in partial output.

```py
spark.read.format('xml').option('rowTag','rowtagname').option('valueTag','valuetagname').load(vlSrcFile)
```

Dataframe having all the nested elements of xml along with the root elements as columns of dataframe